# Noobie problem with using parameters within SQL on Delphi 10.3

Tags: sql, delphi, parameters

I'm sure I'm doing something silly here, but here goes - excuse my noobness.

I'm experimenting with Delphi to try and write a simple app. I'm currently using SQLlite with the chinook demo database, which lists a few artists and albums.

I have managed to connect a ComboBox to a field in the DB to select the artist name.

I then want to fill a grid of the artist albums, using the ComboBox selection as a parameter within that statement:

```
select * from albums JOIN artists ON albums.artistid = artists.artistid WHERE artists.name=:selection
```

If I populate 'selection' manually in the parameters tab of the query object, it works fine.

But I need :selection to come from the ComboBox, for which I think I need to do something like:

```
FDQuery1.ParamByName('selection').AsString := 'ComboBox1.text'
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out where I would put that bit of code? The docs I am reading say: To put a parameter marker into the SQL text, use the : syntax. Then assign corresponding values using the Params collection.

If I expand out the Params bit under the query I don't see anywhere to put it. Making a new one doesn't seem to give me the option to do that either. If I switch to code view, I don't see a section with my SQL query in it to put it in there manually. Maybe a view thing?

Apologies if this is a really stupid question. Just starting out with Delphi!

Answer (score 0):

The OnSelect event of the combobox is one place to update the query.

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDQuery1.ParamByName('selection').AsString := ComboBox1.Text;
  FDQuery1.Open();
end;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!. After a little fiddling that now works. My next step will be figuring out why it only works on the first selection and not subsequent ones, but that's one for tommorow :)

Comment: You need to close your query before changing the parameter value. Works the first time, since the query hasn’t been opened yet. Add an `FDQuery1.Close;` at the top of the routine.

Comment: Yup that got it. Many thanks to yourself and all that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I generally have a procedure "BuildQuery" on a form which I call when the form is initially displayed (FormShow), or when the dropdowns change (OnSelect) or a "Search" button is pressed.

In that procedure, Clear and re-add your SQL to the query, it will automatically detect and add the parameters as you go.

Then do as you did but without the single quotes, then Open your query.

Comment: Awesome thanks, this solved my second problem of it only working on the first selection. Just to help my understanding as to why it solved it, if the parameter is changed, and the query re-opened, why is it necessary re-add the SQL statement at that stage, as it hasn't changed?

Comment: @RichardStevens you don't need to reset the SQL query itself each time. Once prepared, it stays prepared until you unprepare it, or you disconnect the DB. As long as the query stays prepared, you can reuse it, simply updating the parameter values as needed. If that is not working for you, then you need to provide a [mcve] demonstrating exactly how you are using it

Comment: I add the SQL each time to allow for multiple dropdown filters, if I leave one drop down empty, I ignore it from the SQL code.